# WritePrinter fails with "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while printing"

Tags: python-3.x

Have seen this error in multiple threads but nothing that fits the error puzzle.

Python 3.8.6, pywin32 301 installed via pip

The error started after rewriting Qt code that prints a special QString to a DataMax printer in PLZ mode into Python. We originally thought that the issue was with the special python string we created so we simply substituted a "Fail" string in place of the more complex PLZ string and LiClipse still has the same error.

```
    import win32print

    # Create the PLZ string to send to the printer
    # "MM/dd/yyyy"
    timeStamp   = strftime("%m/%d/%Y", localtime())
    
    labelString = "CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~";
    labelString += "^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ"
    labelString += "^XA"
    labelString += "^PW450"
    labelString += "^LL0450"
    labelString += "^FT80,100^A0N,40,82^FH\^FDPROGRAM^FS"
    labelString += "^FT144,140^A0N,40,82^FH\^FDLOAD^FS"
    labelString += "^FT19,305^A0N,120,223^FH\^FDFAIL^FS"
    labelString += "^FT124,406^A0N,28,52^FH\^FD%s^FS"%timeStamp
    labelString += "^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ"        
            
    p = win32print.OpenPrinter("Dmax4310e")
    win32print.WritePrinter(p, labelString)
    p = win32print.ClosePrinter(p)
```

So far we have tried changing labelString to "Fail" in the call to win32print.WritePrinter() but got the same error message. This just seems odd that WritePrinter is saying it wants a bytes-like object when the WritePrinter API is calling for a string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original Qt code used a qPrintable() on the original string. qPrintable() is supposed to encode the QString as a 'uft-8' so we looked to see if this had anything to do with the problem. It seems in python when the original labelString is declared, python3 is not encoding it as a 'utf-8', which I thought was it's default setting. When I see something declared in python as a string and the debugger is calling it a string I incorrectly assumed that it was already encoded as 'utf-8'. So the final solution was to labelString.encode('utf-8') to make the WritePrinter() call happy. We also needed to add a StartPagePrinter() and EndPagePrinter() to encapsulate the WritePrinter call.

```
    try:
        p = win32print.OpenPrinter("Dmax4310e")
        win32print.StartDocPrinter(p, 1, ("Python test RAW print", None, "raw"))
        win32print.StartPagePrinter(p)
        win32print.WritePrinter(p, labelString.encode('utf-8'))
        win32print.EndPagePrinter(p)        
        p = win32print.ClosePrinter(p)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```